# Using nested boost::binds

Tags: c++, boost-bind

```
Compiler: g++ 4.4.3
Boost...: 1.49.0
OS......: Ubuntu
```

Note: It's been 15 years since I seriously used C++, so I'm relearning and learning new things as I also try to learn Boost.

Given the following code:

```
1.      class Beta {
2.      public:
3.          std::string name();
4.      }
5.      
6.      class Alpha {
7.      public:
8.          Beta m_beta;
9.      }
10.     
11.     Alpha one;
```

For various reasons, I wanted to use boost:bind to achieve
the same result as if "one.m_beta.name()" were called.  I
thought the following would do it:

```
12.     boost::function<std::string(Alpha)>
13.         b = boost::bind(
14.             &Beta::name,
15.             boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta, _1)
16.         );
17.     cout << "NAME = " << b(one) << "\n";
```

But when I compile (g++ 4.4.3 on Ubuntu) I get the following
error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const Beta*’ to ‘Beta*’

After looking at the actual type definition resulting from
lines 13-16, it looks like line 15 is becoming 'const Beta*', but
the bind wrapping it expects 'Beta*'.

However, this DOES work:

```
30.     boost::function<std::string(Beta)>
31.         p1 = boost::bind(&Beta::name,_1);
32.     boost::function<Beta(Alpha)>
33.         p2 = boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1);
34.     std::cout << "NAME = " << p1(p2(one)) << "\n";
```

But I really don't want to carry around a lot of intermediate variables.
It did make me think that there must be some way to get the
first version to work as well.  I've already tried the
following as replacements for line 15, but they all give out
one or another error at compilation time too.

```
50. (boost::function<Beta&(Alpha)>)(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
51. (boost::function<Beta(Alpha)>)(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
52. (boost::function<Beta*(Alpha)>)(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
53. boost::protect(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
54. boost::ref(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
55. const_cast<Beta*>(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
56. const_cast<boost::function<Beta(Alpha) > >(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
57. const_cast<boost::function<Beta*(Alpha) > >(boost::bind(&Alpha::m_beta,_1))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well one thing to note is that bind is now standard (in `<functional>`). There's no need to use Boost anymore, since even GCC 4.4 supports it.

Comment: I'd almost guarantee that the actual issue is a (symptom of the) failure of perfect fowarding in C++99/03. Somewhere a `Beta` is being accepted as a `Beta const&`.  You might try compiling with --std=c++0x and using `std::bind`; that might have been implemented to do perfect forwarding.

Comment: Note that for (what I assume to be) your synthetic example it would very likely be customary to declare `Beta::name` as `std::string name() const;`. This would in all likeliness avoid the error (although the question still is very relevant in spirit).

Comment: Many thanks to all of you! Twansbury's answer does exactly what I needed, but I'm going to give the other suggestions a try as well.

Comment: @LucDanton Unfortunately, Alpha and Beta are stand-ins for two classes in a third party library that while I have source, I'm not supposed to modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly specify a `Beta&` return type for the nested `boost::bind`:

```
boost::function< std::string( Alpha ) > b =
  boost::bind(
    &Beta::name,
    boost::bind< Beta& >( &Alpha::m_beta, _1 ) );
```

The reason the `const Beta*` and `Beta*` conversion errors are occurring is the result of [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers) having the same behavior as [`boost::mem_fn`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html#Purpose), which states:

> `mem_fn` also supports pointers to data members by treating them as functions taking no arguments and returning a (const) reference to the member.`

Thus, the nested-bind is returning a `const Beta&`, which is an invalid instance to invoke the non-const `name()` member function on `Beta`.

Comment: With Boost 1.50 there are also some pains when passing the result of `boost::bind` to `boost::function`. If the signature of `b` is changed to `std::string(Alpha&)` this compiles however.

Comment: Finally, `std::bind` (even in tandem with `std::function`) does not appear to exhibit this problem. (Which is conforming to the specification TTBMK.)

Comment: Many thanks to all of you!  Twansbury's answer does exactly what I needed, but I'm going to give the other suggestions a try as well.